# Rear wheel not centred

Tags: rear-wheel, adjustment

I've been trying to fit a second rear wheel to a fracing frame rebuild and I've noticed it is very off-centre. You can see from the pictures that it is much closer to the non-drive side than drive side.

Is this more likely to be a problem with the dishing, or with the axle/hub or something else.

Picture of seatstays

[image]

Picture of chainstay

[image]

Picture of driveside dropout.

[image]

Picture of non-driveside dropout.
[image]

Thank you.

I checked the wheel was set in the dropouts correctly. It now seems to be centred when you look between the seatstays (just under the brake) but is almost rubbing against the non-drive-side chain stay.

I checked the frame alignment, measuring the string just by the seatstay.  The gap between the string was about 94mm, and the the non-drive string was a coupel of mm closer than the drive side. So it does seem slightly out of alignment, but would this be enough to explain the wheel almost touching the chainstay?

Thank you.

Comment: Are there any axle spacers or nuts installed on one side but not on the other? What happens when you flip the whole wheel around? (obviously you won’t be able to ride, it’s just an easy way to check for dishing) Could also be just an installation issue since you have horizontal dropouts. Btw: you need new tyres, the current one is completely worn through down to the threads.

Comment: Just to make sure, is your rear axel aligned correctly (is it straight in the dropouts)? It could just be you have one farther up/down. Looks like it could possibly be the non-drive-side wheel dropout. Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you able to spend some time checking the frame for alignment?  You will need some string, a good ruler, and some nuts/bolts to check the dropouts for alignment.

Comment: Also, try flipping the wheel in the dropouts.  Then look to see if the wheel is still to the left or if its now leaning to the right.  That helps pick if the distortion is in the wheel or the frame.   (Also, are you holding a drone to take these photos ? )

Comment: Thanks everyone. When I flip the wheel then it is now leaning to the right. @criggie, Does this mean dishing is one of the issues? I will also check the frame alignment, but I did try the wheel in another frame and it seemed to have the same issue : suggests it is the wheel and not the frame?

Comment: @love2phish - I've pulled the rear axle as far back as it can go. The derailleur hanger takes up some of the dropout space on the driveside. Not sure if that is standard?

Comment: @michael. What am I looking for regarding spacers? There are more spacers on the non-drive side, whcich I think is to try and get the freewheel as close to the chainstays as possible. There are also locking nuts on both sides. Thank you.